# Custom string properties in interface builder

Tags: cocoa-touch, interface-builder

Is there a simple way to expose, say, NSString or UIColor properties of a class such that they can be modified in interface builder?

This would be useful e.g. for adding color properties to a custom view (which are then used programmatically) so that they can be manipulated in Interface Builder as is appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/custom-views-in-interface-builder-using.html) article from Cocoa with Love describes how to do what you want with Interface Builder Plug-ins for Mac development.  Unfortunately, it is currently not possible to use IBPlugins with the iPhone SDK (note the [Interface Builder Plug-in Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IBPlugInGuide/CreatingPluginBundle/CreatingPluginBundle.html) only appears in Mac OS X documentation, not iOS documentation).

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 8 there are two new properties added, @IBInspectable and @IBDesignable. Here's a full write up.

http://www.weheartswift.com/make-awesome-ui-components-ios-8-using-swift-xcode-6/

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to add a custom "non-IBOutlet" attribute but I suggest you to add a UILabel to make use of the text attribute of it, and of cause release that when the view is loaded.